# Random colors on generated buttons

Tags: javascript, html-table

I made a code that generates me a table and 32 buttons. 
I have an id associated with each button. The problem is that, the color also generated randomly, is only inserted on the first button of the table. 
How is this possible?

```
 window.onload = function createTable()
 {
 var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
 var tbl=document.createElement('table');
 var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
 var color = '#';

 tbl.setAttribute('id', "tableID");

 var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');          

 for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
 {
     var tr = document.createElement('tr');               

     for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++)
     {
         var td = document.createElement('td');           
         var bt = document.createElement('button');       

         for (var k = 0; k < 6; k++)                    
         {
         color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
         }

         bt.id = "button" + idx;                            
         console.log("IDX: " + idx);             
         td.appendChild(bt);                           
         idx++;                          
                     tr.appendChild(td)                            
         console.log(bt);
         bt.style.background = color;
    }
    tbdy.appendChild(tr);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset `color` var to `#` again before `k` loop

```
color = '#';
for (var k = 0; k < 6; k++) 
....
```

Also you need to declare `idx` before using it

```
var idx = 0;
for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++)
....
```

---

**EDIT**

Implementing bg color change on button click

Add this code after all finished

```
var buttons = Array.prototype.slice.call(tbl.getElementsByTagName("button"));

buttons.forEach(function(btn){
   btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
       document.body.style.backgroundColor = btn.style.backgroundColor;
    });
});
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE Based on Bhavik's Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/L9fkN/2/)**

Comment: Oh how I didn't think about before. And do you know if there is a way to associate to each button generated, a command that allows me to change the background with the color of the pressed button? such this:

bt.setAttribute('onclick', 'chColor(color)');

function chColor(color)
{     
      var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
      body.style.bgColor = color;
}

but color is a formal variable..

Comment: Ok. But i resolved without your solution. But thanks, you're very helpful for me :D Have good day!

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>***[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9fkN/)***</kbd>

@Batu has already mentioned the mistake of defining the color.....

***Complete working code***

```
 window.onload = function createTable() {
     var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
     var tbl = document.createElement('table');
     var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
     var idx = 1;

     tbl.setAttribute('id', "tableID");

     var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');

     for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         var tr = document.createElement('tr');

         for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
             var td = document.createElement('td');
             var bt = document.createElement('button');

             var color = '#';
             for (var k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
                 color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
             }

             bt.id = "button" + idx;
             console.log("IDX: " + idx);
             td.appendChild(bt);
             idx++;
             tr.appendChild(td)
             console.log(color);
             bt.style.background = color;
         }
         tbdy.appendChild(tr);
     }
     tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
     body.appendChild(tbl);
 }
```

---

*Update* <kbd>***[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9fkN/3/)***</kbd> with `click` event listener on each button

Comment: Oh how I didn't think about before. 
And do you know if there is a way to associate to each button generated, a command that allows me to change the background with the color of the pressed button?

Comment: @user3344186 see the updated answer.. Click on any button the color will change..